# Como faço um Total Corrente?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma Query feita que pega todas as fatura de um cliente especifico e nela aparece todas as informações de pagamentos e saldo atual, como mostra a imagem do excel Ex: **Img1**

A ideia é somar os **valores em falta** na coluna **saldo** Ex:

**Valor em Falta** é
0+518820=**518820 Saldo**;
518820+2777750 = **796570 Saldo**
E por ai vai...
[image: Imagem do Exercício em Excel...]

Aqui vai o meu scripts que criei para fazer o exercício.
AS TABELAS QUE ESTÃO A SER TRABALHADA É AS DA **FACTURAÇÃO(ft)** E **CONTA CORRENT(cc)**

```
SELECT ft.nmdoc, ft.fno, ft.fdata,  ISNULL(cc.deb,cc.cred) "Valor Doc",  ISNULL(cc.debf,cc.credf)Valor_Pago,
ISNULL((cc.deb-cc.debf),(cc.cred-cc.credf)) Valor_em_Falta, 
ISNULL(++(cc.deb-cc.debf),(cc.cred-cc.credf)) Saldo,
--ISNULL(SUM(@saldo ),0),
ft.pdata Dt_Vencimento 

FROM cc RIGHT JOIN  ft ON cc.ftstamp=ft.ftstamp 

where ft.nome ='JOAQUIM TESTE & FILHO,LDA'

GROUP BY ft.nmdoc, ft.fno, ft.fdata,ft.pdata ,cc.deb,cc.cred,cc.debf,cc.credf

order by ft.fdata
```

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Criar um *running total* em SQL Server é relativamente simples.
Não tendo todo o contexto, acredito que a consulta abaixo resolve o problema:

```
SELECT      ft.nmdoc
        ,   ft.fno
        ,   ft.fdata
        ,   Valor_Doc       = ISNULL(cc.deb,cc.cred) 
        ,   Valor_Pago      = ISNULL(cc.debf,cc.credf)
        ,   Valor_em_Falta  = ISNULL((cc.deb-cc.debf),(cc.cred-cc.credf)) 
        ,   Saldo           = SUM(ISNULL((cc.deb-cc.debf),(cc.cred-cc.credf))) OVER (ORDER BY ft.fdata)
        ,   Dt_Vencimento   = ft.pdata 
FROM        cc 
RIGHT JOIN  ft ON cc.ftstamp = ft.ftstamp 
WHERE       ft.nome ='JOAQUIM TESTE & FILHO,LDA'
GROUP BY    ft.nmdoc
        ,   ft.fno
        ,   ft.fdata
        ,   ft.pdata 
        ,   cc.deb
        ,   cc.cred
        ,   cc.debf
        ,   cc.credf
ORDER BY    ft.fdata
```